# Finding generalized eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

I would like to know how to find the generalized eigenvectors to the following matrix $A$, so that I can express $A$ as $PJP^{-1}$. $$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -3 & 1\\ 1 & 5 & -1\\2 & 6 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ I have already found the eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$ which has algebraic multiplicity of 3 and geometric multiplicity of 2. The corresponding eigenvectors to this eigenvalue are $$v_1=\begin{bmatrix} -3\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix} \quad\quad \text{and} \quad\quad v_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$$ I know that I need to solve either $(A-2I)w = v_1$ or $(A-2I)w = v_2$ to find a generalized eigenvector $w$. However, both system of equations have no solutions. I need some guidance on how to find the generalized eigenvector, or if there is some other way for me to decompose my matrix.

Comment: The road you did take was the right one. Try again and check the computations

Comment: Notice that there are also other eigenvectors, namely all the linear combination of the two you found

Comment: *Hint*: $A-2I$ is a rank 1 matrix, meaning that you can write it as $vw^T$ for some vectors $v,w$.

Comment: @Exodd Okay, I have tried the linear combination $v_1+2v_2$ and then solved $(A-2I)w = v_1+2v_2$ and that gave me a solvable system of equations with $w = \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ as one of the possible generalized eigenvectors. Hence $P = \begin{bmatrix} -3&1&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $J = \begin{bmatrix} 2&0&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2 \end{bmatrix}$. However when I computed $PJP^{-1}$, it did not equal $A$. Do you mind explaining what went wrong?

Comment: You have to use $w$, $v_1+2v_2$ and another linearly independent eigenvector (like $v_1$) to build $P$

Comment: @Exodd Ohhhh thank you so much!! I finally got it!! :)